# GDF or SIF or RDF conversion to obj or collada

Tags: 3d, rdf, mesh, collada

Are there any libraries for converting Geographic Data Files ([GDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_Data_Files)) or Standard Interchange Format ([SIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Interchange_Format)) or RDF to obj or collada?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?  When you say RDF, do you Resource Description Framework?  GDF and SIF are both geospatial, whereas that RDF is much more general.  What do you mean by obj and collada?